# Windows Mingw Make error -

Tags: windows, compilation, makefile, mingw, jitsi

I'm trying to compile Jitsi in windows, and Mingw make is not working for me. Can you help me out?

```
build-installation-wix-base:
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: D:\code\jitsi-master\release\windows\versionupdate.properties
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\code\jitsi-master\release\windows\tmp\light
     [exec] Makefile:41: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

The makefile looks like this in line 41:

```
$(cygwin.target.dir)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe: "$(cygwin.target.dir)/config.h" registry.c run.c "$(cygwin.target.dir)/run.res" ../setup/nls.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) registry.c run.c "$(target.dir)/run.res" ../setup/nls.c $(LDFLAGS) -o "$(target.dir)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe" $(LIBS)
    -"$(MINGW_HOME)/$(MACHINE)/bin/strip.exe" "$(target.dir)/$(TARGET_BASENAME).exe"
```

I can't compile it with cygwin because its throwing tchar.h not found error.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mingw, you should probably run `mingw32-make` instead of `make` from cygwin distribution. They are using different path convetions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WindowsPC "Command" window to enter the commands then make sure to add the path for MinGW install directory (in my case it is C:\MinGW) to the windows PATH. Only then "mingw32-make" executable path is found. Usually you add C:\MinGW\bin for all the executables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).